# webtests symfony 2.5 with Fosuserbundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit, fosuserbundle

I try make test with authentication fosuserbundle, but still is fail, i find solution for symfony 2.3 but it doesn't works

https://gist.github.com/deltaepsilon/6391565

i also try create client by two funcitons

```
protected function createAuthorizedClient2()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $container = $client->getContainer();

    $session = $container->get('session');
    /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager */
    $userManager = $container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    /** @var $loginManager \FOS\UserBundle\Security\LoginManager */
    $loginManager = $container->get('fos_user.security.login_manager');
    $firewallName = $container->getParameter('fos_user.firewall_name');

    $user = $userManager->findUserBy(array('username' => 'admin'));
    $loginManager->loginUser($firewallName, $user);

    // save the login token into the session and put it in a cookie
    $container->get('session')->set('_security_' . $firewallName, serialize($container->get('security.context')->getToken()));
    $container->get('session')->save();
    $client->getCookieJar()->set(new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId()));

    return $client;
}

protected function createAuthorizedClient()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $container = static::$kernel->getContainer();
    $session = $container->get('session');
    $person = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getRepository('BergUserDataBundle:UserLogin')->findOneByUsername('admin');

    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($person, null, 'main', $person->getRoles());
    $session->set('_security_main', serialize($token));
    $session->save();

    $client->getCookieJar()->set(new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId()));

    return $client;
}
```

Comment: Any specific error messages?

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer the recommended way of testing with an authenticated client.

The new recommended way is much simpler - to submit plain old HTTP credentials and then tell your test environment firewall to authenticate via this method instead of the FOS User Provider.

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/http_authentication.html